# uint and char casting for unicode character code

Tags: c#, .net, unicode

Can someone explain exactly what is going on with this code:

```
var letter= 'J';
char c = (char)(0x000000ff & (uint)letter);
```

I understand it is getting the unicode representation of the character, however I don't fully understand the role of:

```
(0x000000ff & (uint)letter
```

What is the purpose of 0x000000ff and the casting of the letter to (uint) and is there a short hand way of achieving the same result?

Thanks

### Update

OK, looks like most people think this is a bad example, I didn't want to include the whole class but I suppose I might as well so you can see the context. From [Reference Source's WebHeaderCollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebHeaderCollection.cs,483):

```
  private static string CheckBadChars(string name, bool isHeaderValue)
    {
        if (name == null || name.Length == 0)
        {
            // emtpy name is invlaid
            if (!isHeaderValue)
            {
                throw name == null ? 
                    new ArgumentNullException("name") :
                    new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.WebHeaderEmptyStringCall, "name"), "name");
            }

            // empty value is OK
            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (isHeaderValue)
        {
            // VALUE check
            // Trim spaces from both ends
            name = name.Trim(HttpTrimCharacters);

            // First, check for correctly formed multi-line value
            // Second, check for absenece of CTL characters
            int crlf = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; ++i)
            {
                char c = (char)(0x000000ff & (uint)name[i]);
                switch (crlf)
                {
                    case 0:
                        if (c == '\r')
                        {
                            crlf = 1;
                        }
                        else if (c == '\n')
                        {
                            // Technically this is bad HTTP.  But it would be a breaking change to throw here.
                            // Is there an exploit?
                            crlf = 2;
                        }
                        else if (c == 127 || (c < ' ' && c != '\t'))
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.WebHeaderInvalidControlChars), "value");
                        }

                        break;

                    case 1:
                        if (c == '\n')
                        {
                            crlf = 2;
                            break;
                        }

                        throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.WebHeaderInvalidCRLFChars), "value");

                    case 2:
                        if (c == ' ' || c == '\t')
                        {
                            crlf = 0;
                            break;
                        }

                        throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.WebHeaderInvalidCRLFChars), "value");
                }
            }

            if (crlf != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.WebHeaderInvalidCRLFChars), "value");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // NAME check
            // First, check for absence of separators and spaces
            if (name.IndexOfAny(InvalidParamChars) != -1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.WebHeaderInvalidHeaderChars), "name");
            }

            // Second, check for non CTL ASCII-7 characters (32-126)
            if (ContainsNonAsciiChars(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(SR.GetString(SR.WebHeaderInvalidNonAsciiChars), "name");
            }
        }

        return name;
    }
```

The bit of interest is:

```
char c = (char)(0x000000ff & (uint)name[i]);
```

Comment: `var letter= "J";` should be `var letter= 'J'`

Comment: @xanatos Thanks for the correction, it was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You're parsing HTTP headers, right? That means you *shouldn't* be using (any) unicode encoding.

HTTP headers must be 7-bit ASCII (unlike the request data)<sup>1</sup>. That means that you should be using the ASCII encoding instead of the default. So while you are parsing the request bytes, you have to use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` instead of `Encoding.Default.GetString`. Hopefully, you're not using `StreamReader` - that would be a bad idea for quite a few reasons, including the (likely) encoding mismatch between the headers and the content of the request.

**EDIT:**

As for the use in Microsoft source-code - yeah, it happens. Don't try to copy those kinds of things over - it *is* a hack. Remember, you don't have the test suites and quality assurance Microsoft engineers have, so even if it does in fact work, you're better off not copying such hacks.

I assume that it's handled this way because of the use of `string` for something that *in principle* should be either "ASCII string" or just `byte[]` - since .NET only supports unicode strings, this was seen as the lesser evil (indeed, that's why the code explicitly checks that the `string` *doesn't* contain any unicode characters - it's well aware that the headers *must* be ASCII - it will fail explicitly if the string has any non-ASCII characters. It's just the usual tradeoff  when writing high-performance frameworks for other people to build on.

Footnotes:

1. Actually, the RFC (2616) specifies US-ASCII as the encoding, probably meaning ISO-8859-1. However, RFC is not a binding standard (it's more like a hope of making order out of chaos :D), and there's plenty of HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1 clients (and servers) around that do not in fact respect this. Like the .NET authors, I'd stick with the 7-bit ASCII (encoded char-per-byte, of course, not *real* 7-bit).

Comment: HTTP headers can be ISO-8859-1 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5987 *By default, message header field parameters in Hypertext Transfer
   Protocol (HTTP) messages cannot carry characters outside the ISO-
   8859-1 character set*) but the point is the same: 1 `byte` becomes 1 `char`, with a mapping 1:1 of the value.

Comment: @xanatos Hah, I wonder if that's always been there (even the original HTTP 1.1 RFC 2616 talks about "US-ASCII", which probably means ISO-8859-1). It also allows UTF-8 in 5987, apparently. In any case, tons of clients assume ASCII, so it's still a good idea to just stick to the 7-bit ASCII (That is, with every 8-bit zero, not *real* 7-bit. That would be silly). Just like when you don't specify an charset, it *means* iso-8859-1, while most clients assume it means the client is supposed to *guess* at the encoding :D

Comment: @Luaan Still, if you use `ISO-8859-1` it has the advantage that there is a conversion 1:1 between the bytes with values 0-255 and the `char` with value 0-255, so it is always safe. Then you can re-decode them with another encoder without losing information.

Comment: @Luaan you're a great healer! :-) Many thanks for the succinct answer.

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, that's definitely a good point. It means no data is ever lost on the way. Of course, it only applies to the variant .NET uses for it's strings - for example, using UTF-8 would mean you'd lose (well, mangle) characters above 127 by stripping the extra byte(s). `Ä` is fine in ISO-8859-1 and UTF-16 (just a simple 196 single byte, with a leading zero-byte for UTF-16), while in UTF-8, it's `195, 132`. Stripping the first byte leaves you with `„` instead of `Ä`.

Answer (score 1):

What this code does is not the conversion to Unicode. If anything, it is the other way around:

The part `0x000000ff &` basically discards the second byte of the unicode letter and transforms it into a letter that is only one byte long. Or more precisely: It keeps only the most significant byte and discards all other - which is the same for a `char` because it has a size of two bytes.

I am still of the opinion that this makes no sense, because it leads to false positives: Unicode letters that actually use both bytes will simply lose one of these bytes **and therefore become a different letter**
I would simple get rid of this code and use `name[i]` everywhere you use `c`.

Comment: I wouldn't say *second* - unicode can have more bytes per character than two, as well as less. It just takes the lowest byte, no matter what the other bytes look like (or how many there are).

Comment: @Luaan: The char type in C# is two bytes in size, so there is no way that there can be more than two bytes.

Comment: Yeah, but that's way up on the `char` level - that just means that those characters are going to actually be represented as a surrogate pair - that's even *worse* - not only will you not strip half of the unicode letter, you will in fact add pseudo-ASCII characters that don't make any sense. I know you're not trying to say that using something like this is a good idea, but it's even more complicated than just changing some letters in the output. The `char` will only ever have two bytes, but the unicode letter can have multiple `char`s.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of 0x000000ff and the casting of the letter to (uint)

to get character with code from [0..255] range: `char` takes 2 bytes in memory

e.g.:

```
var letter= (char)4200; // ၩ
char c = (char)(0x000000ff & (uint)letter); // h

// or
// char c = (char)(0x00ff & (ushort)letter);

// ushort (2-byte unsigned integer) is enough: uint is 4-byte unsigned integer
```